# Vim mouse wheel vertical scrolling just one line

Tags: vim, mouse

How do I need to adjust my vimrc to make vertical scrolling smoother? I want to achieve that one iteration of the mouse wheel just scrolls one instead of three lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The relevant information is at `:help scroll-mouse-wheel`:

> ```
> For the Win32 GUI the scroll action is hard coded.  It works just like
> dragging the scrollbar of the current window.  How many lines are scrolled
> depends on your mouse driver.  If the scroll action causes input focus
> problems, see intellimouse-wheel-problems.
>
> For the X11 GUIs (Motif, Athena and GTK) scrolling the wheel generates key
> presses <ScrollWheelUp>, <ScrollWheelDown>, <ScrollWheelLeft> and
> <ScrollWheelRight>.
> ```

So, if you're on Windows, you can only influence this globally through your driver, whereas on X, you can do

```
:map <ScrollWheelUp> <C-Y>
```

etc.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I use OS X (Mavericks). But it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 9):

try adding this into your vimrc:

```
   map <ScrollWheelUp> <C-Y>
   map <ScrollWheelDown> <C-E>
```

P.S. the best solution would be: don't use that mouse-wheel...

Comment: I use `j`, `k`, `h`, `l`, `ctrl`+`d`, `ctrl`+`u`, `H`, `M`, `L`, etc, but sometimes I just like to use my trackpad to sweep a file.